# How to get html elements from different class xpath?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml, xpath

I know how to get a list of DIVs of the same css class e.g

```
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class1">2</div>
```

using xpath `//div[@class='class1']`

or
div have multiple classes, e.g

```
<div class="class1 class2">1</div>
```

using xpath `//div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]`

But how if  div have different classes, e.g

```
<div class="class1">1</div> 
<div class="class2">2</div>
```

What will the xpath like then?

Comment: may be div[@class^='class']  this my first time heard about xpath  but ^ in selector mean get all elements starts with this

Comment: `$("div[class^='class']")` will get all the class starting with class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query: `//div[contains(@class,'class1') or contains(@class, 'class2')]`

This syntax would be better though: `//div[class^='class']` if you want to grab all div tags that contain 'class' at the beginning of the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help me:)